# TFS Project Collection Service Accounts

Tags: azure, hyperlink, edit

Set Service Hooks in TFS and create Azure Storage

I can't finish after setting:

`Access denied: [XXX]\Project Collection Service Accounts requires the following usage rights on the StrongBox to perform this action: Create StrongBox Drawer`

Maybe I need to have permissions?

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need **Edit subscriptions** and **View subscriptions**  permissions  to set up a subscription.

By default, only project administrators have these permissions. To grant them to other users directly, you could also use `tfssecurity.exe` from the command line. For example:

```
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/DefaultCollection ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/abcdef00-abcd-0000-0000-abcdef000000 ViewSubscriptions n:fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com ALLOW
```

and

```
Copy
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/DefaultCollection ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/abcdef00-abcd-0000-0000-abcdef000000 EditSubscriptions n:fabrikamfiber4@hotmail.com ALLOW
```

The GUID is the ID of the project. You can get it using the [Projects REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

After this you should be able to create the service hook and save it.
[image]